# How to join across three tables while counting from two of them

Tags: sql, join, sqlite

I have three tables: domains, signups, and tracking.

I currently have a list of all domains and the number of visitors using this query:

```
SELECT sites.id, sites.domain, count(tracking.domain) as tracked FROM sites
LEFT JOIN tracking ON sites.domain = tracking.domain
GROUP BY sites.domain
ORDER BY sites.id;
```

Now, I would also like to get the count (per domain) from a new table called signups.

I've gotten as far as this:

```
SELECT sites.id, sites.domain, count(tracking.domain) as tracked, signers.cc FROM sites
LEFT JOIN tracking ON sites.domain = tracking.domain
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT signups.domain, count(*) as cc FROM signups
GROUP BY signups.domain
) as signers
USING (domain)
ORDER BY sites.id;
```

But that doesn't seem to be quite right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Anything wrong with doing mutliple queries?

Comment: No, but I just thought it'd be easy to do and I was over looking something.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I just left out a final `GROUP BY` at the end..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: (you can add the outer joins as you like, i'm just pointing you in the right direction here)

```
with trackingCount as
(
select sites.domain,
       count(1) as tracked
  from sites,
       tracking
 where tracking.domain = sites.domain
 group by sites.domain),
signupsCount as
(
select sites.domain,
       count(1) as signedUP
  from sites,
       signups
 where signups.domain = sites.domain
 group by sites.domain)
select *
  from trackingCount tc,
       signupsCount sc
 where tc.domain = sc.domain;
```

Gives:

```
domain  tracked signedUP
A       4       2 
B       1       4
```

You can play around with it here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/bec74/2